# Alexander-Conway polynomial of the sum of two knots

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

It is known that the Alexander polynomial of the sum of two knots $K=K_1\#K_2$ is equal to the product of the Alexander polynomial of the two summands $K_1$ and $K_2$. If the same true for the Alexander-Conway polynomial (AC(trefoil) $= 1 + z^2$) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true for the Alexander-Conway polynomial.

If you still have doubts, think that both the polynomials are special cases of the HOMFLY-PT polynomial.